# update adapter time gridview scroll automatically on top

Tags: android, gridview

I am integrating endless grid view. end less is working perfect. but on scroll while update my adapter data at that time grid view goes to top. and i need that it should be maintain it's current position where it is.

For the feel adapter in grid view i used below code.

```
myDataAdapter = new ProductGridAdapter(activity, results, null);
gridView.setAdapter(myDataAdapter);
gridView.invalidate();
myDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Can any one tell me that how can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have a variable that captures the top element of your grid view that is being displayed. Then whenever you invalidate the view, use `setSelection()` function. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29

Answer (score 0):

I got the way. in first time i add adapter in list view and after that i just update the adapter.

```
if (myDataAdapter == null)
        {
            myDataAdapter = new ProductGridAdapter(activity, results, null);
            gridView.setAdapter(myDataAdapter);
        }
    else
        {
            myDataAdapter.updateData(results); //update adapter's data
            myDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```